# how to use android with broken touch and adb not enabled

Tags: adb, root-access, 4.1-jelly-bean, broken-screen

Scenario
Phone is rooted with android 4.1 and stock recovery 
Screen works but touch input does not because of broken digitzer
Usb debugging is enabled but computer is not authorised it asks for authorization and screen is locked by pin#  otg not supported
Is their a way to authorize adb access and use it

Answer (score 1):

If only touch stopped working and screen is properly visible and  your device supports OTG then you could try the USB OTG with keyboard and mouse to go to developer settings and turn on usb debugging or use the device

Comment: Otg is not supported